# Custom python tool setting table field as a parameter?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters

I am somewhat new to Python, but I'm trying to create a custom python tool with 3 parameters, a workspace, a table and a Field from that table. I have the parameters set up like this:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    parm0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName = 'SSURGO geodatabase',
    name = 'geodatabase',
    datatype = "DEWorkspace",
    parameterType = "Required",
    direction = "Input")

    parm0.filter.list = ["Local Database"]

    parm1 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName = "Table",
    name = "Table",
    datatype = "DETable",
    parameterType = "Required",
    direction = "Input")

    parm2 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName = "Fields",
    name = "Fields",
    datatype = "Field",
    parameterType = "Required",
    direction = "Input",
    multiValue = True)

    parameters = [parm0, parm1, parm2]
    return parameters
```

I would like to create code in the updateParameters section that will allow the user to select a table and select a field from the fields within the table. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In the tool interface properties you set the 'Obtained from' for the field to the table it will then offer a field in the chosen table. You shouldn't need to play with the validator to get this done.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameterDependecies to achieve that. Simply add a line

```
    parm2 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName = "Fields",
    name = "Fields",
    datatype = "Field",
    parameterType = "Required",
    direction = "Input",
    multiValue = True)
    parm2.parameterDependencies = [parm1.name]
```